# Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be real numbers, and set $a_{ij} = a_ia_j$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be real numbers, and set $a_{ij} = a_ia_j$. Consider the $n \times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$.
Then

1. It is possible to choose $a_1.\dots,a_n$ such that $A$ is non-singular
2. matrix $A$ is positive definite if $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is nonzero vector
3. matrix $A$ is positive semi definite for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$
4. for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, $0$ is an eigen value of $A$

I have calculated upto $3\times 3$ that determimant is $0$ but I have no idea how to conclude rigoriously. please help?

Comment: Consider $Av$ where $v=(a_2,-a_1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: I do not understand what  that implying to which option to my question

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257066/let-a-i-j-a-ia-j-1-i-j-b-where-a-1-a-2-ldots-a-n-are-real-n?rq=1

Comment: Well, what happens when you do what I suggested, that is, when you compute $Av$? What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.
With $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, we can more conveniently write $v\mapsto \langle a,v\rangle a$ instead of $v\mapsto Av$, which simplifies computations.

1. If $n=1$, then $a_1=1$ is a valid choice and makes $A$ regular (the identity). For $n>1$, there exists nonzero $v$ with $\langle a,v\rangle = 0$, hence $A$ is singular. (To be explicit, either some $a_i$ is $=0$ and then the $i$th standard base vector $e_i$ is in the kernel; or $a_1,a_2$ are nonzero and $a_1e_2-a_2e_1$ is in the kernel. That is: Such a choice is possible if and only if $n=1$.
2. $\langle Av,v\rangle = \langle \langle a,v\rangle a,v\rangle = \langle a,v\rangle^2\ge 0$, so we see that $A$ is positive *semi*-definite. But if $n>1$ or $a=0$, it is defnitely not positive definite, as follows from 1. Hence the claim is true only for $n=1$
3. As shown in 2, this is correct
4. As shown in 1, this is correct only if $n>1$.

So the only claim that is unrestrictedly correct, is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few comments: 
First, 4. implies that $A$ is always singular, answering 1. Follow Gerry Myerson's advice to prove 4 (basically, you are trying to show that the first two columns are linearly dependent). Now 2. cannot be true since 0 is an eigenvalue.

Also, it may be helpful to think of $A$ as the product $a a^T$ where $a$ is the column vector of the $a_i's$. Edit: you can use this to show 3.